# Err: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property:

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I dont know where actually im going wrong can someone help to get rid of this error.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="nifty", catalog="portfolio")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id",scope=NiftyDTO.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"latestData","data"})

public class NiftyDTO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



@Id
@Column(name="niftyid")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;



@Column(name="time")
private String time;

@Column(name="trdVolumesumMil")
private String trdVolumesumMil;

@Column(name="declines")
private int declines;

@Column(name="trdValueSum")
private String trdValueSum;

@Column(name="trdValueSumMil")
private String trdValueSumMil;

@Column(name="unchanged")
private int unchanged;

@Column(name="trdVolumesum")
private String trdVolumesum;

@Column(name="advances")
private int advances;






public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getTrdVolumesumMil() {
    return trdVolumesumMil;
}

public void setTrdVolumesumMil(String trdVolumesumMil) {
    this.trdVolumesumMil = trdVolumesumMil;
}

public int getDeclines() {
    return declines;
}

public void setDeclines(int declines) {
    this.declines = declines;
}

public String getTrdValueSum() {
    return trdValueSum;
}

public void setTrdValueSum(String trdValueSum) {
    this.trdValueSum = trdValueSum;
}

public String getTrdValueSumMil() {
    return trdValueSumMil;
}

public void setTrdValueSumMil(String trdValueSumMil) {
    this.trdValueSumMil = trdValueSumMil;
}

public int getUnchanged() {
    return unchanged;
}

public void setUnchanged(int unchanged) {
    this.unchanged = unchanged;
}

public String getTrdVolumesum() {
    return trdVolumesum;
}

public void setTrdVolumesum(String trdVolumesum) {
    this.trdVolumesum = trdVolumesum;
}

public int getAdvances() {
    return advances;
}

public void setAdvances(int advances) {
    this.advances = advances;
}

public NiftyDTO() {
    super();
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "nifty", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<NiftyDataDTO> niftyDataDTO;

public Set<NiftyDataDTO> getNiftyDataDTO() {
    return niftyDataDTO;
}

public void setNiftyDataDTO(Set<NiftyDataDTO> niftyDataDTO) {
    this.niftyDataDTO = niftyDataDTO;
}

public NiftyDTO(Long id, String trdVolumesumMil, String time, int declines, String trdValueSum, String trdValueSumMil, int unchanged, String trdVolumesum, int advances, Set<NiftyDataDTO> niftyDatumDTOS) {
    this.id = id;
    this.trdVolumesumMil = trdVolumesumMil;
    this.time = time;
    this.declines = declines;
    this.trdValueSum = trdValueSum;
    this.trdValueSumMil = trdValueSumMil;
    this.unchanged = unchanged;
    this.trdVolumesum = trdVolumesum;
    this.advances = advances;
    this.niftyDataDTO = niftyDataDTO;
}



}
```

This is my another class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="NiftyDataDTO", catalog="portfolio")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id", scope=NiftyDataDTO.class)


 @JsonIgnoreProperties({"ptsC","per","trdVol","trdVolM","ntP","mVal","wkhi","wklo","wkhicm_adj","wklocm_adj","xDt","cAct","previousClose","dayEndClose","yPC","mPC"})

public class NiftyDataDTO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "dataId")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name="symbol", nullable = false)
private String symbol;

@Column(name="open")
private float open;

@Column(name="high")
private float high;

@Column(name="low")
private float low;

@Column(name = "itp")
private float itp;

@XmlTransient
@ManyToOne(optional = true ,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "niftyid", referencedColumnName = "niftyid")
private NiftyDTO niftyDTO;

@JsonIgnore
public NiftyDTO getNiftyDTO() { return niftyDTO;}

public NiftyDataDTO(Long id, String symbol, float open, float high, float low, float itp, NiftyDTO niftyDTO) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.symbol = symbol;
    this.open = open;
    this.high = high;
    this.low = low;
    this.itp = itp;
    this.niftyDTO = niftyDTO;
}


//Getter And Setter


public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSymbol() {
    return symbol;
}

public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
}

public float getOpen() {
    return open;
}

public void setOpen(float open) {
    this.open = open;
}

public float getHigh() {
    return high;
}

public void setHigh(float high) {
    this.high = high;
}

public float getLow() {
    return low;
}

public void setLow(float low) {
    this.low = low;
}

public float getItp() {
    return itp;
}

public void setItp(float itp) {
    this.itp = itp;
}

public void setNiftyDTO(NiftyDTO niftyDTO) {
    this.niftyDTO = niftyDTO;
}

public NiftyDataDTO() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}






}
```

Stack Trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1582) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
at com.socgen.portfolio.PMSApplication.main(PMSApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: 
    default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
atorg.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:860) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:340) ~[spring-orm-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319) ~[spring-orm-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1641) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown 
target entity property: com.socgen.portfolio.domain.NiftyDataDTO.nifty in com.socgen.portfolio.domain.NiftyDTO.niftyDataDTO
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:769) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:729) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1697) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
... 29 common frames omitted

2017-06-08 14:38:03.305  WARN 142244 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' is defined)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: NiftyDataDTO has no nifty

Comment: can u please be more clear im not getting you @StanislavL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mappedby` must have a valid property name as value:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "niftyDTO", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<NiftyDataDTO> niftyDataDTO;
```